Pylance reportArgumentType with Pydantic’s BeforeValidator
I’m writing a pydantic type similar to ImportString called ImportPlugin which imports and optionally calls objects and returns the call result. For example:
from typing import Annotated, TypeVar
from pydantic import BaseModel, BeforeValidator

class MyModel(BaseModel):
    length: ImportPlugin[int]

MyModule(length={"obj": "builtins.len", "args": ([1,2,3],)}).length  # 3

My ImportPlugin type is defined like so:
T = TypeVar('T')

def generate_plugin(plugin_dict: Dict[str, Any]):
    return _Plugin.model_validate(plugin_dict).generate()

ImportPlugin = Annotated[T, BeforeValidator(generate_plugin)]

Where the _Plugin class is a generic BaseModel that handles importing and calling the object.
This works fine, but Pylance draws a red squiggly line under the dictionary input to MyClass, flagging it as a reportArgumentType. Is there a way to solve this issue? Pylance should understand that the input type should be what the BeforeValidator expects, not T.
